# Sound and vibration on background until touched

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, awesome-notifications

I am working on a Flutter application where I am utilizing the `awesome-notifications` package to handle notifications. I want to implement a feature where a background sound and vibration play continuously until the user interacts with the notification.

I have explored the Awesome Notification documentation, but I couldn't find a direct solution for achieving this behavior. Has anyone successfully implemented continuous background sound and vibration until a notification is touched using the `awesome-notifications` package in Flutter?

Any guidance, code snippets, or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Additional Information:

Flutter Version: 3.16
Awesome Notification Package Version: 0.8.2

```
@pragma('vm:entry-point')
Future<void> initializeNotification() async {
  const int insistentFlag = 4;
  final Int64List vibrationPattern = Int64List(4);
  vibrationPattern[0] = 0;
  vibrationPattern[1] = 4000;
  vibrationPattern[2] = 4000;
  vibrationPattern[3] = 4000;

  await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
    null,
    [
      NotificationChannel(
        channelKey: 'society',
        channelName: 'My Channel Name',
        channelDescription: 'Notification Example',
        importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
        channelShowBadge: true,
        defaultColor: const Color(0XFF9050DD),
        ledColor: Colors.white,
        playSound: true,
        defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Alarm,
        // criticalAlerts: true,
        vibrationPattern: Int64List.fromList(<int>[insistentFlag]),
        // enableLights: true,
        enableVibration: true,
      ),
    ],
  );
}


AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: id,
          channelKey: 'society',
          title: payload['title'],
          body: payload['body']!,
          payload: payload,
          autoDismissible: false,
          wakeUpScreen: true,
          category: NotificationCategory.Call),
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(label: 'Label1', key: 'key1'),
        NotificationActionButton(label: 'Label2', key: 'key2'),
      ]);
```

Works Fine on foreground but for background notifications it vibrates only once and sound is also short